# Use OSX .dylib with Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, dynamic-linking, dylib

Is it possible to reference an Mac OS X .dylib in an Android.mk file, as we do for .so files?

I have a C++ project compiling on my computer that I need to use with the NDK. The project uses two dylib. The compilation works, but linking does not (I'm having "undefined reference to [...]" messages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, its not.  A .dylib has a binary format that the underlying Linux OS doesn't understand.  You need to use a .so file.  Although if you have the source code for the library, compiling it to .so should require minimal changes, perhaps as little as a shim layer

Comment: Are you sure? The project is also using OpenCV, and I only have .dylib for it, no .so file.

Comment: Open CV is easily available as .so or as source code.  Without that it may compile (as the Java portion only cares that the appropriate native function exists in the Java code) but it will fail either at link or runtime because it won't be able to load the library or find the C function.

Comment: You're right, I installed OpenCV with home brew but also downloaded the android version to get its .mk file, which may be referring the .so files also provided.